# How to merge multi json files into one without duplicates using jq?

Tags: jq

I have multiple json files and all have the same parent element. I want to merge all the child elements into one file with one parent element without duplicate keys(take only the last occurrence of a key into the final file).

Example.

file1.json

```
{
    "parent1": {
        "child1": {
            "prop1":"val1"
        },
        "child2": {
            "prop2":"val2"
        }
    }
}
```

file2.json

```
{
    "parent1": {
        "child1": {
            "prop4":"val4"
        },
        "child3": {
            "prop3":"val3"
        }
    }
}
```

expected.json

```
{
    "parent1": {
        "child1": {
            "prop4":"val4"
        },
        "child2": {
            "prop2":"val2"
        },
        "child3": {
            "prop3":"val3"
        }
    }
}
```

I have taken 2 files just for example, but actually I have multiple files in the directory.
For 2 files I understand this can be done by
`jq -S -s '.[0] * .[1]' file1.json file2.json`
But how to do it for multiple files using jq?

Comment: @oguzismail I corrected the json. And prop4 wasn't in the expected result because I wanted to consider the value for the 1st occurrence of the key. However, I have updated the question. I actually want the value of last occurrence of a key in case of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

In the question, you ask for the generalization of '*' for multiple objects.  Here is a stream-oriented generalization:

```
def star(s): reduce s as $x ({}; . * $x);
```

With your two files, an invocation along the lines of:

```
jq -n '
  def star(s): reduce s as $x ({}; . * $x);
  star(inputs)
' file*.json
```

would produce the output shown below, which however differs from your expected.json, thus suggesting that your requirements might need clarification.

#### Output

```
{
  "parent1": {
    "child1": {
      "prop1": "val1",
      "prop4": "val4"
    },
    "child2": {
      "prop2": "val2"
    },
    "child3": {
      "prop3": "val3"
    }
  }
}
```